# How to save response returned as application/pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, https, express

I am making an API call to SmartSheet that returns the worksheet as a PDF file.

This is the relevant documentation - [link](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.tcwgf9lkll36)

My question is how do I accept the PDF response and save it locally in nodeJs? I am making use of the `https` module and I know how to make the request, but I can't understand how do I accept the response:

```
https.request(options, function (response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        //What do I do with the body here?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That depends. How do you want store downloaded PDFs? If you want to store them in local file system, then you can stream data directly into the file.

For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    hostname: 'google.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, function (response) {
    response.on('end', function () {
        // We're done
    });

    response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file'));
});

req.end();

req.on('error', function (err) {
    // Handle error here
});
```